# Call a function on clicking a dropdown but before selecting any option in Angular

Tags: html, angular, dropdown

We are trying to display key value pairs of an object in the form of drop downs. There are two: right and left. When the left one is selected with a value (test1), the right drop down should display a list which relate only to the value selected on the left. So we are trying to filter the values on the click of the second drop down itself. [image]Have tried ng-click, ngOnChanges but these emit events only when an option has been selected. Is there any way to call a function when the drop down element has been clicked only?

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Can you, instead of an image, share a minimal sample StackBlitz to work with along with some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

The native Browser `onClick` should work. Or in an Angular idiomatic way `(click)="myFunc()"`.

But you could also think fill the dropdown on the right when the dropdown on the left is changed. Since this would mean the right dropdown is already filled when you click on it, this is preferrable as there will be no visible lag or flickering.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it `(change)` [here is example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c8wnlm?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```
<select (change)="selectChangeHandler($event)">
        <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
        <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
        <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
    </select>
    <p><span>You selected: </span><b>{{selectedDay}}</b></p>
```

//event handler for the select element's change event

```
  selectChangeHandler (event: any) {
    //update the ui
    this.selectedDay = event.target.value;
  }
```

https://blog.kevinchisholm.com/angular/get-value-selected-dropdown-menu-item/